# $[T]_{B_1,B_2} = [T]_{E}$, then is it necessary that $B_1 = B_2 = E$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose $B_1$ and $B_2$ are ordered basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and $E$ is the standard basis. Let $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation. Suppose we know that $[T]_{B_1,B_2} = [T]_{E}$, then is it necessary that  $B_1 = B_2 = E$?

Comment: The linear map $0$ is the same in every basis.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n=1$ (so, $E = \{1\}$) and $B_1 = B_2 \neq E$. Notice that if $T : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is linear, then there is a real number $a$ such that $T(x) = ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Then $[T]_E = (a) = [T]_{B_1,B_2}$.

Comment: What about if $n \ge 2$?